# Manhwa about a boy who was transported to another world for his safety, and later on was sent back to be the Duke of the North fighting monsters

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am looking for a manhwa where the male lead was transported to another world by god and is in a child protective program for his protection. He is then assigned to one of the workers. She takes care of him and, later on, he returns to his world. The girl decides to go meet him in his world, only to discover that the time difference between worlds is large and that he is now an adult. She asked him three questions to be sure it's really him.

Comment: So, going off the title, the boy was originally from a world with nobility and monsters? And what/who was he sent away to be protected from? The monsters, or his own family?

Comment:  more than 2 months searching for it, I just found it. It's called Dear My Hunny Bunny .

Comment: You should post the answer using the 'Your Answer' field, so that you can earn some reputation. Also, if you come back 48 hours or more after you posted the question, you can mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark by the voting buttons, which is this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved.

Comment: Thank you very much 

Answer (score 3):

It's called *[Dear My Hunny Bunny](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/dear-my-hunny-bunny)*.

[image: Cover of Dear My Hunny Bunny]

> Jay is an 8th rank public official. She works as a special guardian, and her mission is to heal children whose souls have been deeply wounded. Ludwig shuts himself off from the world. He seems as if he's forgotten how to smile. However, he learns what it means to be happy through Jay, and Jay cherishes him as her own precious Hunny bunny.

Comment: It's great that you figured it out; could you include a link and a synopsis to help other people who might also be looking for this?

Comment: I [edit]ed a quick summary and cover page in, as well as a link to MyAnimeList, which is generally fairly safe for non-infringing links.